# Change fontsize in PStricks globally

Tags: pstricks

I am using [DIA](http://dia-installer.de/index.html.de) for making some Latex graphs.
However, DIA can only export those to PSTricks.tex. Unfortunately, the fontsizes inside this are very small although they were looking quite well inside DIA.

I am aware I can use something like `\huge`inside the `\rput{}{}`, however everytime I change my DIA-picture, I have to redo this for every \rput command (there are around 30 in each picture).

Is there an easy way to do this one time globally?

Comment: Try at the very beginning: `\everypsbox{\huge}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{pspicture}(...)
\Huge
...
\end{pspuciture}
```

Doesn't work for labels at axes.